# WickrME installed successfully but not opening

Tags: software-installation, 17.10

I downloaded WickrMe and installed but its not opening. I am using 17.10 with 64 bit.

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you expect to happen and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them *in their entirety* in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. Please **[edit]** your post to add information instead of posting a comment. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: i did same as listed on official website it listed in launcher but did not opened

Comment: That answers only part of my questions. Please read beyond the first part of the second question of my previous comment. Thanks.

Comment: no error if there is an error why i am hiding it. no error it showing to me. nothing in the log file

Comment: I have no idea why people omit that but it's very common for people to describe an issue with only "it doesn't work" or "there's an error" and I only learn after a few questions back and forth that there was a very descriptive error message that they chose to not relay.

Comment: but there is not a error even not an error of "Not Responding" it just load and stuck  and close and also not working in services

Answer (score 1):

According to [Wickr website](https://me-download.wickr.com/#/version/me)
It only runs on **Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit**

For use with Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit:

> 1. Uncompress WickrMe.
> 2. This file contains 4 files, 2 `.deb` and 2 `.sha` files.
> 3. Run `gdebi wickr-qt_5.8.1_amd64.deb`, followed by `gdebi WickrMe_4.00.04-01_amd64.db`.
>
> Wickr Me should then appear in your applications menu.
>
> **The current build only works with Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit, and not 16.10.**